# Getting Caret Position Inside Any Application in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, window, location, caret, cursor-position

I'm making a Singlish-English Word Prosessor.When user typing in a active window's TextBox
those letters were automatically converted to the Sinhala language.I did that hard part with sendKeys() Function.But Now I want to set my application windows's location at Active Window's Blinking cursor(Caret) position.So It will easy to user with English-Sinhala Translation thing.How can I do this with VB 2010.Can any one help me.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CaretPosition.aspx) ?.It works for Microsoft Office applications too.
However it's in C# which you will be able to transform into VB.NET

Comment: I saw it.I managed to get only caret position for relevant textfield in active window.I want to get caret position on screen not in textfield.But that app works fine with screen position.Can you convert that code to vb for me.I think i stucked with some methods that in c# when it converting to vb